# A Simple Generalization of the Littlewood Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Littlewood Conjecture asserts that for all real numbers $r$ and $s$, and for every
$\epsilon > 0$, the inequality $|x(rx-y)(sx-z)| < \epsilon$ is solvable in integers $x, y, z$ with $x > 0$.

The Littlewood conjecture is clearly a consequence of the following:

For all real numbers $r$ and $s$, and for every $\epsilon > 0$ the inequalities

$|x(rx-y)| < 1, \,\,|sx-z| < \epsilon$ are solvable in integers $x, y, z$ with $x > 0$.

Does anyone know a counter-example to the latter statement? Does anyone know of any references to it in the literature?

Note that the inequality $|x(rx-y)|  <  1$ always has infinitely many solutions $(x,y)$ with $x > 0$. This is a consequence of Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem. So it is natural to ask:  "How does $sx$ behave mod 1 as $(x,y)$ runs through the solutions of  $|x(rx-y)|  <  1$?"  For example, can  the closure of the  $sx$ mod 1 contain some non-empty open set and be disjoint from another?

Experiments with Sage seem to "suggest" that  the numbers $sx$ are either dense mod 1 or have just finitely many limit points mod 1,  depending on whether the numbers $1,r,s$ are linearly independent over the rationals.  Again, any counter-examples or references relevant to this statement would be  appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$ \vert x(r x-y)\vert <1$ implies that $y/x$ is a convergent of the continued fraction expansion of $r$. This can be used to construct a counter-example as follows. Consider for $r$ for example a fairly large irrational quadratic real number with constant continued fraction $[l,l,l,l,\dots]$. Let $d_1 < d_2 < d_3,\dots$ be the sequence of denominators appearing in the convergents of $r$.
Consider $s$ of the form $s=1/2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n/d_n$
with $\alpha_i\in\{0,1}$ recursively defined such that the distance of $d_i(1/2\sum_{n=1}^i\alpha_i/d_i)$ to the nearest integer is $\geq 1/4$. This implies that 
the distance of $d_i(1/2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n/d_n)$ to the nearest integer is 
$>1/4-\epsilon$ for $l$ large enough. Indeed, the sequence $d_1,d_2,\dots$ grows roughly
like a geometric sequence of argument $l$. This implies that $d_i(1/2\sum_{n=i+1}^\infty 
\alpha_n/d_n)$ is at most of absolute value roughly given by $1/(2l(1-1/l))=1/(2l-2)$ which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $l$ large.

Comment: Roland, It is not quite true that the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $r$ coincide with the solutions of `$x(rx-y)| < 1$` in the way you describe.  Non-convergents can satisfy such an inequality and moreover there can be solutions $(x,y)$ with $x$ and $y$ not relatively prime.  See Rockett and Szusz, Continued Fractions, Section II.5. Does this fatally break the estimate given in the last two sentences of your argument? I'm not sure.... but it needs another look .  (Note: This is a corrected version of my initial comment)

Comment: You are of course right. My attempts to fix the resulting complications were unsuccessful. Perhaps it is more promising to consider for $r$ the golden number for which my claim (without error of my part) is indeed correct. Unfortunately it is to small to give useful error-terms and it is difficult to push through the end of the argument.

Comment: I can't quite follow what your argument is, but I would point out that it is a known fact that if a sequence $d_1,d_2,...$ grows geometrically (in the strong sense that there is a positive constant c such that all ratios are at least 1+c) then there must exist a real number s and a positive epsilon such that for every n the distance from $sd_n$ to the nearest integer is at least epsilon. 

Comment: But that settles it! As I think Roland was suggesting, if $r=(1+5^{1/2})/2$, then the positive values of $x$ that appear in solutions to the inequality `$|x(rx-y)| < 1$` are exactly the Fibonacci numbers, which grow exponentially in the sense you describe.  Then the $s$ of your known fact gives a counter-example to my generalization of Littlewood's conjecture. 

Maybe for ANY  irrational $r$ the $x$'s will grow exponentially, but I'm not sure about this.

I think I see how to attack the proof of your "known fact". Is there a name  attached to it?

Thanks. 

Comment: @gowers: Do you have a reference for the "known fact" of your last comment? I can prove it if the ratio $d_{n+1}/d_n$ is at least $2+c$, but "$1+c$" is giving me trouble. 

Answer (score 3):

This answer pieces together the various comments made by Roland Bacher, SJR and 
gowers previously. The proposed generalization of Littlewood's conjecture is false.

As suggested by Roland and SJR, take $r$ to be the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.
Then $x|rx-y| \le 1$ only when $x$ runs over the Fibonacci numbers $F_k$.  Now 
we want to show that there is an irrational number $s$ such that $F_k s$ is 
bounded away from integers.

As suggested by gowers there do exist such $s$ for any lacunary sequence $n_k$ 
(that is a sequence with $n_{k+1}/n_k \ge 1+ c>1$ for all large $k$), and so in 
particular for the Fibonacci numbers.  This is related to a conjecture of Erdos, 
that for any lacunary sequence $n_k$ there exist irrational numbers $\alpha$ with 
$n_k \alpha$ not being dense $\mod 1$.  Erdos's problem was settled independently 
by de Mathan and Pollington in a stronger form, showing that there exist many such $\alpha$.  We need in fact that the values $\mod 1$ are bounded away from $0$.  This 
is worked out in detail using Pollington's argument in a recent nice preprint of 
Haynes and Munday (see Lemma 1 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0208 ).

Comment: "This answer pieces together the various comments made by Roland Bacher, SJR and gowers above." For some value of the word, "above".

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the paper online, but this looks rather like a question that is answered by a paper of Pollington and Vellani. Here is a link to an abstract of the paper. (It may be clear from the abstract that they answer your question -- I am feeling lazy and so have not checked.)

http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=121841

Comment: @gowers: Thanks for the reference. The theorem mentioned in the abstract doesn't seem to settle my question, at least directly... Maybe I can use the result mentioned in the abstract to push through an argument like the one that Roland gave? 

Comment: Hmm, I have now thought a bit more and I think this paper is irrelevant -- though it is interesting in its own right. I like your question too. 